# What muscles perform rotation of the elbow joint about the axis of the arm, while keeping the hand fixed?

Tags: muscle, arms

If I extend my arm straight and place my palm against a surface, I can rotate my elbow joint about the axis of the arm, while keeping my hand fixed. (ie: I can rotate my elbow joint without rotating my hand)

What are the names of the muscles perform this rotation? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the movement as you described it. When you say "around the axis of the arm", do you mean around the humerus or the radius?

Comment: @Alec, I'm keeping my arm completely straight with the palm of my hand flat against a surface. I'm twisting the elbow joint back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biceps, Triceps and pronator teres && supinator muscle.

You are using the muscles that normally your forearm uses to twist, but because you focus on not changing the position of your hand your arm twists instead.

http://www.innerbody.com/image/musc03.html

Comment: Thanks. I have a followup question. Forearm twisting happens at two joints as far as I can see. The wrist joint, and the elbow joint. I feel like twisting of these two joints must use different muscles, because in my left arm, I can twist these two joints independently. But in my right arm (with issues since my birth), I can rotate the wrist joint, but I can't rotate the elbow joint at all. What muscles rotate the wrist joint? And what muscles rotate the elbow joint?